# Running python script through a bash script is causing an unexpected output

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use a software called plasmidFinder and I'm running into some difficulty. plasmidFinder uses two databases but when I try to use a bash script to batch run plasmidFinder on several files, it fails to use the gram positive database.

I've tried to reinstall the database, run the script within Docker instead of executing a Docker instance each time I run the script, changing the database file name to force the script to use the gram positive database.

```
#!/bin/bash

# runs plasmidFinder on each fasta file in current directory

for FILE in `ls` ;
 do
    mkdir $FILE.output
    sudo docker run --rm -it -v $PLASMID_DB:/database -v $(pwd):/workdir plasmidfinder -i $FILE -o $FILE.output -x
 done
```

Yes, I realise that for FILE in `ls`; is not the good bash coding practice but my main priority is getting the script to work :)

Here's what happens when I run plasmidFinder sequentially.

```
{'plasmidfinder': {'results': {'Enterobacteriaceae': {'enterobacteriaceae': 'No '
                                                                            'hit '
                                                                            'found'},
                               'Gram Positive': {'gram_positive': 'No hit '
                                                                  'found'}},
                   'run_info': {'date': '08.05.2019', 'time': '17:58:06'},
                   'user_input': {'file_format': 'fasta',
                                  'filename(s)': ['file1.fasta'],
                                  'method': 'blast'}}}
```

Here's what happens when I run plasmidFinder through the bash script I provided.

```
{'plasmidfinder': {'results': {'Enterobacteriaceae': {'enterobacteriaceae': 'No '
                                                                            'hit '
                                                                            'found'},                               
                   'run_info': {'date': '08.05.2019', 'time': '17:58:06'},
                   'user_input': {'file_format': 'fasta',
                                  'filename(s)': ['file1.fasta'],
                                  'method': 'blast'}}}
```

Notice how in the 2nd example here that the gram positive database is not used.

Is there something wrong with my bash script? How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  In order to help, it may be helpful if you edit your question to include any steps you used to diagnose the problem yourself.  For example, what is the complete output of the program when ` -x` is added to the `#!` line in your `bash` script?  Also, how exactly do you _run plasmidFinder sequentially_?

Comment: Where are you setting `$PLASMID_DB`?

Comment: @MichaelJaros That was it, I thought that setting it within the terminal before running the script was enough but I added a line in the script to set PLASMID_DB and it now works! Thank you so much, I've spent days on this haha!

Comment: @ginohino Welcome.